# Live Agent - How do I access "Time Since Last Accept" programmatically?

Tags: liveagent, console, chat

We recently implemented Salesforce's Live Agent in our organization. We would like a custom console footer component to display the most available agent for a particular skill. Is there a way to access the values displayed in the the "Live Agent Supervisor" tab - specifically agent status and time since last away - through visualforce / apex?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values from the supervisor tab are not available through the API. The closest you can get to this is by querying the LiveChatTrancript object (the object that stores the chats) and query the createdby or owner field. Not entirely accurate but I think is the closes you can get.

I would recommend doing this considering the amount of effort it will require and will not be 100 % accurate.